# SQLAlchemy: iterating a subquery that returns multiple rows

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a class called `ItemMap` -- a SQLAlchemy representation of an actual SQL-Server database table called `item_map`.

```
class ItemMap(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'item_map'
    code = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    item = Column(String)
```

Given a Python datetime variable `d` and string `code`, the following query computes the datediff in days between the `ItemMap.date` column and `d`, sorts in descending order and then returns the first two rows (for which the `ItemMap.code` column entry is equal to `code`).

```
q = session.query(
    ItemMap,
).filter(
    func.datediff(text('day'), ItemMap.date, d) >= 0,
    ItemMap.code==code,       
).order_by(
    ItemMap.date.desc(),
).limit(2)
```

So for instance, setting `d = datetime.datetime(2016,8,2,12,45)` and `code='V'`, and then running `pd.DataFrame(q.all())` returns:

```
   code       date  item
0     V 2016-08-02   V-1
1     V 2016-08-01   V-1
```

This is the correct behaviour.

The problem I'm having is that I can't see how to run this logic sequentially for a number of datetime elements defined in a further table (or view or other selectable entity).

So for instance suppose there is another item called `r` representing some database entity possessing a `datetime` column such that the result of running `pd.DataFrame(session.query(r.c.datetime).all())` is

```
              datetime
0  2016-08-02 12:45:00
1  2016-08-04 12:45:00
2  2016-08-09 12:45:00
```

I would like to run the query logic encapsulated in `q` above for each of these elements in sequence and collate the output such that we obtain:

```
   code       date   item
0     V 2016-08-02    V-1
1     V 2016-08-01    V-1
2     V 2016-08-04    V-2
3     V 2016-08-03    V-2
4     V 2016-08-09    V-3
5     V 2016-08-08    V-3
```

It is important that this union-type operation occurs on the server side. So what I'm looking for is a single SQLAlchemy operation along the lines of:

```
q = session.query(
    ItemMap,
).filter(
    func.datediff(text('day'), ItemMap.date, r.c.datetime) >= 0,
    ItemMap.code==code,       
).order_by(
    ItemMap.date.desc(),
).limit(2)\
.iterate_over(r.c.datetime)   # (not a real SQLAlchemy command)
```

Note that iterating over the elements of `r` on the client-side, forming a separate `q` for each and collating via union_all works in principle but in practice is rejected by the database API once the number of elements passes some upper threshold. In my real-life application I need to run this for many orders of magnitude more data than for the stylised examples presented here.

Comment: why don't you want to use SQL which would be executed on the SQL Server side (i.e. should be more efficient) and read results using: `df = pd.read_sql('select ... from tableA join ... where ... order by ...', conn)`, where `conn` is your SQLAlchemy connection (returned by `create_engine`)?

Comment: @MaxU Don't have a problem with a pure SQL solution, though I've tried thinking about is this way and was also struggling to see how that would work. It would be good to have it both ways, but I'm particularly interested in the SQLAlchemy approach since this is how the rest of my application is implemented. Incidentally, on the efficiency point, since SQLAlchemy is just building and issuing SQL, I don't see why a pure SQL approach would necessarily lead to more efficiency (other than in the respect of constructing the SQL on the client-side in the first instance). Or am I missing something?